# Prevent direct url access without permission in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I given different permission for add,edit,view,delete to every user after login. Its perfectly working in header to hide and show. But I want to prevent direct url access without permission.

How can I do it in codeigniter???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do directly as you have to write down the code.
You have to create one common file and then include it in constructor. in common file write down your logic and here you can prevent direct access of url.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20553692)

Comment: user need the way only. so please read the  question @CJ Dennis

Comment: Agree with Coolbuddy. Relevant info regarding the question itself.

Comment: @coolbuddy thanks for your answer. its realy usefull to me.

Comment: thanks guys. happy to help you. :)